# How can I restrict a profile's read access on an object if my org-wide default is public read-only?

Tags: security, sharing

My org has a default of public read-only on a certain object, but I want to set up a new profile that can only see certain records based on criteria. Is this even possible to do? If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing a profile can do is restrict all access to an object or grant total read/write/delete access to an object. To grant record by record access like that, the OWD would have to be private, with sharing rules set up against a role or public group. You can't use sharing rules on a profile.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, there is no way to grant criteria-based read access if the OWD settings are already public read only?

Comment: Correct. Sharing is cumulative, so you can't make a rule that's as restricted or more restricted than OWD to any effect.